# test proportional odds assumption with 2 random variables R ordinal logistic

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, mixed-models, ordinal

I'm using the package [ordinal](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/index.html) in R to run ordinal logistic regression on a dependent variable that is based on a 1 - 5 likert scale and trying to figure out how to test the proportional odds assumption.

My current model is `y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x2*x3 + (1|ID) + (1|form)` where x1 and x2 are dichotomous and x3 and x4 are continuous variables.  (92 subjects, 4 forms).

As far as I know,
-"nominal" is not implemented in the more recent version of clmm.
-clmm2 (the older version) does not accept more than one random variable
-nominal_test() only appears to work for clm2 (without random effects at all)

For a different dv (that only has one random term and no interaction), I had used:

```
m1 <- clmm2 (y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, random = ID, Hess = TRUE, data = d
m1.nom <- clmm2 (y ~ x1 + x2, random = ID, Hess = TRUE, nominal = ~x3, data = d)
m2.nom <- clmm2 (y ~ x2+ x3, random = ID, Hess = TRUE, nominal = ~ x1, data = d)
m3.nom <- clmm2 (y ~ x1+ x3, random = ID, Hess = TRUE, nominal = ~ x2, data = d)

anova (m1.nom, m1)
anova (m2.nom, m1)
anova (m3.nom, m1)  # (as well as considering the output in summary (m#.nom)
```

But I'm not sure how to modify this approach to handle the current model (2 random terms and an interaction of the fixed effects), nor am I sure that this actually a correct way to test the proportional odds assumption in the first place.  (The example in the package tutorial only has 2 fixed effects.)

I'm open to other approaches (be they other packages, software, or graphical approaches) that would let me test this.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Even in the case of the most basic ordinal logistic regression models, the diagnostic tests for the proportional odds assumption are known to frequently reject the null hypothesis that the coefficients are the same across the levels of the ordered factor. The statistician Frank Harrell [suggests here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/medstats/y_94cReelQg) a general graphical method for examining the proportional odds assumption, which is probably your best bet. In this approach you'd just graph the linear predictions from a logit model (with random effects) for each level of the outcome and one predictor variable at a time.